Can a not integrable function but has iterated integrable?
Let $f:[0,1] \times [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as $f(x,y) = 1$ if $x = m/q$ and $y = n/q$ for some integers $m, n, q$ and $f(x,y) = 0$ otherwise. Show $f$ is not integrable on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$
(B) Compute $\int\int(f(x, y)dy dx $ on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$
I already done the first part by Riemann condition, but I have no idea in (b). How can I compute a function when it's not integrable?

Just as a long commentary: the integral that you want to compute can exist although the function is not integrable. Fubini's theorem, under certain hypothesis, ensures that if $A$ is a Jordan-measurable set then the integral of the function over $A$, i.e., the number $\int_A f$, is equal to $\int\int f(x,y) dydx$ and also equal to $\int\int f(x,y) dxdy$. In this case, of course, Fubini's theorem doens't apply. Of course, the iterated integrals have limits in function of the region and as it can be expressed as a region of type 1 and 2. See, for example here.
To do the calculation of $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} f(x,y) dydx$, notice that yo need to calculate the integral from inside to outside. So, when you calculate $\int_{0}^{1} f(x,y) dy$, the variable $x$ is fixed. What can say about $x$ and the definition of the function? That is the key to do the calculation. Can you finish from here?

I think it kind of make the set of y countable, then I can solve the iterated integral? Many thanks!

Umm. Is an argument more elaborated. To compute the inner integral, you can recall the integral of the Thomae's function. If my answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark as accepted. :-)
